# How to read ‘Tridion.ContentManager.config’ file from my ‘Custom resolver’ c# code

Tags: configuration, custom-resolver

Experts,

I need to read a section of `Tridion.ContentManager.config` file from my `Custom resolver` c# code.

Any Idea How to do it?

[image: Custom Resolving]

As per the SDL Live documentation here (login required): http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL_Tridion_2011_SPONE/concept_753C261063AD4B9CA5E4F50BD4FD48E9I, I want to read value for the key **“Title”** for the section **"My.Tridion.CustomResolving"**.  Very similar to the example provided in the docs:

```
private string SCHEMA_TITLES = Config.GetConfig("My.Tridion.CustomResolving", "schemaTitles");
```

However, it does not really explain where the Config class comes from or how to instantiate it.

I am guessing, I will have to use class **“Tridion.ContentManager.ConfigurationSettings”** in the code, but not really sure.

Please help.

Thanks

Saurabh

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I wrote a blogpost about this exact issue: http://albertromkes.com/2014/01/20/custom-resolvers-and-configuration/

In short: you have to load the `Tridion.ContentManager.config` file yourself from the configuration of the calling application (TcmServiceHost, Publisher, etc).

Answer (score 5):

As a new answer to an old question, SDL Tridion Sites 9.1 added the ability to create and read custom configuration files as part of one or more extensions as part of the [add-ons feature](https://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Tridion%20Sites-v2/GUID-28C5ED30-2349-4AA2-AB59-AEBB2A89FDCB).

See how to create a [custom Add-on configuration file](https://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Tridion%20Sites-v2/GUID-5B340E61-76AF-420C-A905-5254ACC1F94D).

Specifically for this question, the "Schema Titles" could be added to the specified JSON to be read and used with the corresponding custom resolver code, with the custom configuration independent of the add-on code.

Answer (score 4):

Honestly, don't know, why do you need it (if you want save key/value pairs you can do it without Tridion configuration handlers).
But if you really want it, I've made fast example.
For next xml:

```
<My.Tridion.CustomResolving>
 <Keys>
  <add key="title"
 </Keys>
</My.Tridion.CustomResolving>
```

You need to have something next:

```
public class NameValueSectionHandler : CentralizedConfigurationSection
    {
        private const string _keyCollectionConfigurationProperty = "Keys";

        public override string Name
        {
            get
            {
                return "My.Tridion.CustomResolving";
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets the Keys.
        /// </summary>
        [ConfigurationProperty(_keyCollectionConfigurationProperty)]
        public KeyCollection KeyCollection
        {
            get
            {
                return (KeyCollection) this[_keyCollectionConfigurationProperty];
            }
        }
    }

 public class KeyCollection : ConfigurationElementCollection
    {
        protected override ConfigurationElement CreateNewElement()
        {
            return new KeySettings();
        }

        protected override object GetElementKey(ConfigurationElement element)
        {
            return ((KeySettings)element).Key;
        }
    }

public class KeySettings : ConfigurationElement
    {
        private const string _keyAttributeName = "Key";
        private const string _valueAttributeName = "Value";

        [ConfigurationProperty(_keyAttributeName)]
        public string Key
        {
            get
            {
                return (string) this[_keyAttributeName];
            }
            set
            {
                this[_keyAttributeName] = value;
            }
        }

        [ConfigurationProperty(_valueAttributeName)]
        public string Value
        {
            get
            {
                return (string) this[_valueAttributeName];
            }
            set
            {
                this[_valueAttributeName] = value;
            }
        }
    }
```

(CentralizedConfigurationSection is from Tridion.Configuration)

Almost forgotten...
After that you need do something like:

```
NameValueSectionHandler handler = Tridion.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.GetSection<NameValueSectionHandler>("My.Tridion.CustomResolving");
```

With help of this handler - you can read your configuration.