# Read Web.Config in Pipeline

Tags: 2011, templating

I have written a WCF service that takes userID and finds complete display name from active directory. In my publishing pipeline I have got creatorID of current page which is compete userid along with domian and I want to call WCF service here to fetch compete user display name from Active directory.

Reason of doing all this is that User name (description) stored in tridion and user name in Active Directory will be different in some cases, therefore I am not using Tridion stored user name.

URL of WCF service will be used but where can I define/store the service url? Can I read `web.config` file in my pipeline?

Is there any other way to do similar thing?

Comment: this could be helpful

http://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/4450/how-to-read-tridion-contentmanager-config-file-from-my-custom-resolver-c-co

Comment: What exactly do you mean with "In my publishing pipeline"? are you trying to access a `web.config` in a TBB in a Page Template, if so, which `web.config`, from where?

Comment: yes I want to access web.config in a TBB of page template. web.config is located at root of my IIS web site. If it doesn't make any sense then is there any other way?

Comment: I don't want to access tridion content manager config, I want to access web.config located at root of my web site folder. If web.config is not the right place then is there any other place where I can store wcf service url?

Comment: Your web.config from your web app is probably on a different machine than your Content Manager Publisher - doesn't make much sense to try to read it at publish time...

Comment: you are right but Is there any other way to configure and read service url?

Comment: I solved it, I included a 'WCF URL' field in publication metadata schema, publication is using this metadata schema, I can access publication in my page template using 'Page.OwningRepository', gives me repository object, which contains metadata xml with my WCF url.